# linux + messages + what is the meaning of "Too many open files (24)" messages

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, syslog

from **/var/log/messages** I see many lines as the following:

```
   Oct  9 10:01:14 Linux_machine15 syslog-ng[14736]: Error opening file for writing; filename='/var/log/remote/102.18.20.44/kern.log', error='Too many open files (24)'
```

I need to understand what is the meaning of the "Too many open files (24)" messages ?

```
 more /etc/security/limits.conf


 *       soft    nofile  8192
 *       hard    nofile  65536
 *       soft    nproc   8391
 *       hard    nproc   16384
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system sets limits, how many open files a process is allowed to have. These limits are usually set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

By default, the limit for open files might be too low, sometimes as low as 1024.

You can increase the limits globally by adding:

```
*          -       nofile          16384
```

You can also set the limits per user or per group, by replacing the asterisk in the first column by `username`, or by `@groupname`.

Comment: just to clarify this - you mean when we write on the same time for example to 2000 files , then OS have limitation about to write to these files ?

Comment: @yael - the limit is for open files, ie for file descriptors. Regardless whether you open them for writing or reading only.

Comment: so what is the number - 24 in the log?

Comment: @yael - the number `24` has nothing to do with the actual number of open files. It is just an error code. Looks like the log comes from Apache, but you only pasted one line without context, so there is not much to work with.

Comment: last question , I update the question with my limits.conf file , how to know if i can to increased the current values ? ( I mean I to know the max values that I can to increase ? )

Comment: @yael -  I am not sure what is the max allowed value. Try 1048575, which for all practical purposes should be as good as unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

There are two configurable limits of how many open files a system may handle. 
To see the hard and soft values, use:

```
ulimit -Hn
ulimit -Sn
```

IIRC most distros set the limit of file descriptors to 1024 per user.
You can remove the limit using `ulimit -n 0`.

To permanently change this, adapt `/etc/security/limits.conf` and reboot system:

```
echo -ne " 
* soft nofile 65536 
* hard nofile 65536 
" >>/etc/security/limits.conf
```

Comment: about - Too many open files , can you describe please what was the root cause of this message ? , or example ?

Comment: The root cause is somewhere in your system, but no one can know it except you.

Comment: so if I want to increase the value - how to know the MAX value ? of hard/soft